# Do Azure VM's being upgraded affect an entire resource group?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-templates

I had an issue this morning that seems to be too big of a coincidence to be an accident.

We have Test and Production virtual machines in the same resource group, as well as other VM's and resources for different departments.

This morning I upgraded our Test virtual machine to a higher level server, and not 1 or 2 minutes later I start getting emails our production server is down.

I instantly panic and make sure I didn't upgrade the wrong server on a Monday morning before I consumed enough caffeine to be fully awake. Luckily, I still had the page open on Azure and I upgraded the correct VM, but it seems these two events have to be related as our production server hasn't had a problem in months.

Do changes to 1 VM affect an entire resource group? If yes I will have to do changes to Test during our upgrade cycles.

Comment: Resource Groups are just bounding-boxes to hold various Azure resources. Mainly for organizational and security purposes. They don't tie services together in any way whatsoever (aside from the fact that, if you delete a resource group, everything inside it gets deleted too).

Comment: I didn't see a way to mark your comment as the answer, the other place did. You both said the same thing, which is what I thought also.

I am just very skeptical that my production outage and my going to the Azure portal and upgrading another VM are unrelated, being that they happened within minutes of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, upgrading (what this even means? changing sku?) a vm doesnt affect any other resources except the VM itself. same holds for almost any other resource.

restarting\shutting down\changing sku on one vm doesnt affect other vms.

Comment: Ok, that was my understanding also prior to yesterday. The odds of my production server going down and requiring restarting to solve the problem, just seem like an incredible coincidence. 

And as for upgrading, I changed the Size. It was an A2 (I think) and now it is a D3 with more memory. 

Thanks for clarifying it for me.